# How to access to HttpRequest in Application_Error in Asp.net Mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an application via .Net framework 4.5 and Asp.net MVC5.
I try to access to Request object in Application_Error but I get "Request is not available in this context" error.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    var req1 = httpContext.Request;
```

also I tried this

```
var req2= HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

while the second code is working fine in Asp.net MVC3 projects.

Any Idea?

Comment: I need this because I have some exceptions that are not thrown from any Controller

Comment: Are those errors thrown from background threads or tasks that you might have started?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, I flick through some assemblies to find some interfaces and some assemblies throw exception then I wrap them into myException and rethrow them. Then I need my exception to be showon on my view, also I want a globlal exception handler since there might be other exceptions and I want to show them in my view

Comment: If the exception is thrown in a background thread what `Request` object do you expect to be able to retrieve? The HttpContext might have been disposed long time ago.

Comment: I get it, I run this code in Application_Start and exception is thrown in RunBuilders(),         
`protected void Application_Start()
{
            RunBuilders();` and Request is not available in Application_Start, so how can I catch and show a userfriendly view for the exceptions that are thrown in Application_Start

Comment: You can't. This doesn't make any sense. In `Application_Start` there's no concept of an HttpContext. You shouldn't be throwing any errors in your `Application_Start`. The best you could do in this case is log the error. But you cannot display anything to the user simply because at this stage there's no concept of an HttpContext.

Answer (score 2):

here you are :-)

```
   protected void Application_Error()
        {
             HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
                if (httpContext != null)
                {
                    RequestContext requestContext =((MvcHandler)httpContext.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
                }
         }
```